# How can I print the content of author.name and description(embed)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to print the content of author.name an description of an embed, but I have no idea how.

```
Error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: author is not defined
```

```
const user = author.name;
  message.channel.send(`${user} !!!`);
  console.log(`${user} !!!`);
```

Example
I want to return the name `"Juan"` of `.setAuthor` and `"text"` of .setDescription from the embed , It is not the name of the author of the message

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor('Juan')
    .setColor('RANDOM')
    .setDescription("text")
      message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: `message.author.username`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved

```
if(message.embeds.length >= 0) 
  {
    let embed = message.embeds
    for(let i = 0; i < embed.length; i++)
    {
      if (!embed[i] || !embed[i].author || embed[i].author.name === null) return;
      {
      const string4 = (embed[i].author.name);
      message.channel.send(string4)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use `message.author.username`

```
client.on((message) => {
const username = message.author.username;
  message.channel.send(`${username} !!!`);
  console.log(`${username} !!!`);
})
```